# turning an embedded linux system into a router LAN/WLAN/WWAN

Tags: networking, networkmanager

I am attempting to establish communication among a network of embedded Linux devices over a small local network. One of the devices, serving as the DHCP server, should have an interface with the broader internet.

I have limited knowledge about networking, which I believe is also impeding my progress in this process.

possible configurations:

- receive signal via 4G and bridge this to the wifi hotspot/ethernet port
- receive signal via the ethernet port and bridge this to the wifi hotspot

what I have working so far:

- ethernet dhcp server
- wifi hotspot
- 4G connection
- wifi connection
- ethernet connection

but not the bridges between them.

system details:
kernel 5.10.72
debian 11 bullseye
arm64/aarch64 architecture
using network manager and dnsmasq

i tried this:
[How to create wireless bridge connection with nmcli](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219887/how-to-create-wireless-bridge-connection-with-nmcli)

but the bridge was unable to be activated.

I'm really not quite sure what direction to look in, there seem to be so many available ways to do this but I can't get any of them to work, brctl, ip.

So far what I see is that network manager bridges connections together and not interfaces

I tried:
`ip link add name wifi-eth type bridge`

but this gives me:
`Error: Unknown device type.`

I tried:
`brctl addbr wifi-eth`

But this gives me:
`add bridge failed: Package not installed`

Does anyone have some advice for me, maybe just resources that can help me?

Comment: it seems you don't have the bridge module - what's the result of `find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -name 'bridge*'`

Comment: Ah is there a kernel configuration that needs to be enabled for this to work?

Comment: No, just wondering if you have the bridge module, you should, but it seems you don't

Comment: I feel like it might be though https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/BRIDGE.html

Comment: isn't that docs for building a kernel? I take it you didn't bother checking if you HAVE the bridge module (wouldn't taken a few seconds rather than the 15 minutes you spent searching for kernel building configuration settings ... you say Debian 11, unless it's some weird device which is "debian based" rather than using actual Debian, then I can't see why `bridge` module would not be present

Comment: can you further describe these `embedded Linux devices`

Comment: I run a custom built kernel, with a debian 11 rootfs built with chroot/debootstrap. So I'm quite familiar with Yocto to build new linux images so it wasnt that much effort.

You can see it as like an expanded Raspberry PI but based on the IMX8MM processor

Comment: `custom built kernel` that explains it then

Comment: The fact that you're working on embedded makes everything more difficult. Then *bridging* (rather than *routing*) Wifi isn't easy, it's certainly not just like bridging Ethernet and it depends. Wireless frames have usually 3 MAC addresses and it's good enough for bridging an Access Point, but might require 4 MACs when (STAtion) clients also want to expose bridged traffic, and maybe same for peer to peer (I don't know much about). See  https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25100/four-layer-2-addresses-in-802-11-frame-header . In comparison Ethernet uses only 2 MACs.

Comment: (that means, once you get all the required missing kernel modules, that won't just work without more tinkering. Not even considering the concept of bridging 4G)

Comment: I feel like it should be able to repackage (or add another layer to it) a packet received over the ethernet connection and pretend as if it itself is sending this message over wifi/celular? I think I might reframe my question and also put it on that stack exchange because I'm very interested in figuring out how this works.